# How to toggle custom WP archive list

Tags: jquery, javascript, archives, categories

Help! I'm trying to toggle the "SideDish Archive" list in the right-hand sidebar of this page – http://my-table.com/sidedish/.

I don't know really anything about javascript. Small company, small budget – so I'm left with tweaking the website, and this list has been a long-time annoyance.

Any help is appreciated (but please dumb down your answers for me)!

Comment: any objections to just using the dropdown option on the widget?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about the theme or plugins you are using.

Since your theme isn't responsive you could get away with the down and dirty approach if you can edit CSS files:

```
/wp-content/themes/mytable/style.css line 262
.content-bar {
  border-right: none;
  width: 890px;
}

/wp-content/themes/mytable/style.css line 181
.right-sidebar {
  display: none;
}
```

Or override by adding your own CSS file.

If @majick's solution is an option that is far better than this answer.